# markdown html-element syntax highlighting fails when line has leading spaces

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown

For some reason, my html elements stop being highlighted when they are preceded by 4 or more spaces.  I use spaces to do indentation for nested elements, so this is quite unfortunate.  This only happens for `.md` files, and not `.html` files, though.  How can I insist that vim highlight my html elements in markdown files regardless of leading spaces?

system: Ubuntu 16.04

vim: version 7.4.1689 (from the repos)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

4 spaces or more are considered as a CodeBlock, which probably why these are not highlighted.

Comment: If you want to complete your answer you could recommend OP to put their cursor on the "wrongly" highlighted text and use this command `echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')` this will show the highlighting group currently used and this should return something line `['markdownCodeBlock']` (I guess it depends on your syntax plugin) but that should convince them your answer is the correct one.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for completing the information.